# Delete folders with many files quickly in WinSCP

Tags: winscp

In WinSCP, if I select a directory and right-click to delete, instead of simply deleting the directory it deletes all the contents one at a time. Depending on the contents and the connection, this can take a very long time.

Is there any way, within the WinSCP interface, I can simply delete a directory as quickly as if I'd used a command like `rm -rf`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is based on the [WinSCP "Useful commands" page entry for "delete"](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_commands#delete) with some important missing steps added.

**These steps you only need to do once:**

1. Right-click some test directory to delete
2. Choose *Custom commands > Customize*
3. Click the "Add" button
4. Under "Description" give it a name of your choice, like "Delete"
5. Under "Custom command" you have a choice:

   - Do you want a confirmation box to pop up? If so, enter: `test "!?Do you really want to delete ?no!" == "yes" && rm -rf !&`
   - Do you want it to just instantly delete? If so, enter: `rm -f -r "!"`
6. Tick the "Apply to directories" checkbox
7. Hit "Okay". You now have a "Delete" option under "Custom commands" any time you right-click a file or folder.

You can now delete any file or folder instantly with this new custom command. It might take a few seconds to reconnect the first time you do this in a session

Comment: +1 for combining the `test` with the `!?prompt?!` pattern.

Comment: Delete shows up as grayed out in Custom commands

Comment: Yeah, how does it work now since the Delete command stays grayed out?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is writing e.g. a PHP script and invoking the deletion from there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123

This will also allow you to delete a folder with essentially native code execution speed instead of the horrendous network overhead when deleting each individual file/folder.